# using dash in python to upload files and plot a bar chart

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I try to make an interactive dashboard using [dash](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components) from plotly. I am a beginner in it therefore I used an [example](http://pbpython.com/plotly-dash-intro.html) to do it.
The code should upload different data files from a certain folder and plot a histogram based on a certain column. The name of each file looks like `"30092017ARB.csv"` (date + ARB.csv). The code loops over all file names in the data-folder and print the name of files in a drop-down bottom. After selecting the name of file it should be uploaded and plot a histogram. I wrote the following code:

```
        import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
#
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np
#

mypath='/Users/Python/BeN_/data/'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]



app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H2("Ausfallsreport"),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id="dataFH",
                options=[{
                    'label': i,
                    'value': i
                } for i in onlyfiles],
                value=" "),
        ],
        style={'width': '25%',
               'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='Mygraph'),
])
@app.callback(
dash.dependencies.Output('Mygraph', 'figure'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('dataFH', 'value')])
def update_graph(dataFH):
    df = pd.read_csv(mypath+dataFH, delimiter=';',encoding='cp1252') 
    # aggregate 
    dfagg = df.groupby('Bestand', as_index=False).agg({'MW': 'sum'})
    # make strings for x-axis 
    x=["BE-"+s for s in[str(s) for s in [int(x) for x in dfagg.iloc[:,0].tolist()]]]
    y=dfagg.ix[:,1].tolist()

    trace = go.Bar(x=x, y=y, name='Declined')

    return {
        'data': [trace],
        'layout':
        go.Layout(
            title='Customer Order Status for {}'.format(dataFH),
            barmode='bar',
            yaxis=dict(tickformat=".2%"))
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I get the following [image: output] under `http://127.0.0.1:8050/` .
The problem is that I do not get any Bar chart. Could someone help me to figure out why.

Comment: get rid of the dropdown attribute `value = ' '` and replace it with `placeholder = "select a file"`.     
the attribute `value` references a value from the dropdown which should exists among the options in the dropdown. If you do not want to make any initial selection then replace `value` with with the attribute `placeholder` which could be an instruction or a fake selection, a hint if you will and shows up greyed out in the field of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't figured it out yet, the issue is that when a user initially connects, it triggers your callback. And you're setting the initial value of dropdown to

```
dataFH=" "
```

which causes

```
df = pd.read_csv(mypath+dataFH ...
```

to throw an error because that file doesn't exist.

Different ways to fix this, but one way is to check if mypath+dataFH is a file within your callback and return an empty list for the trace if it's not a file:

```
def update_graph(dataFH):
    if isfile(mypath+dataFH):
        df = pd.read_csv(mypath+dataFH, delimiter=';',encoding='cp1252') 
        # aggregate 
        dfagg = df.groupby('Bestand', as_index=False).agg({'MW': 'sum'})
        # make strings for x-axis 
        x=["BE-"+s for s in[str(s) for s in [int(x) for x in dfagg.iloc[:,0].tolist()]]]
        y=dfagg.ix[:,1].tolist()

        trace = go.Bar(x=x, y=y, name='Declined')
    else: 
        trace=[]

    return {
        'data': [trace],
        'layout':
        go.Layout(
            title='Customer Order Status for {}'.format(dataFH),
            barmode='bar',
            yaxis=dict(tickformat=".2%"))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will try it.